# Running 2 programs concurrently using shared memory

Tags: c, parallel-processing, shared-memory

I have a main function that has an array of ints I am trying to add to shared memory.  I am then trying to run 2 sort programs concurrently to sort the array.  Here is what I have so far along with where I am stuck:

```
int sId;
int *arr,*s;
pid_t pid1, pid2;
key_t key;
size = 100; 
key = 1047;
arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
sgmtId = shmget(key, size, IPC_CREAT | 0666)

arr = shmat(sId, NULL, 0);
s = arr;
for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    s[i] = i;
}

if ((pid1 = fork()) == 0) {
   /* Not sure how to run sort.c */
}
if ((pid2 = fork()) == 0) {
   /* Run sort.c a second time */
}
.
.
```

How can I pass a pointer to the shared memory array to sort.c for both processes?

Comment: What platform is this on? C doesn't know about things like multiprocessing, shared memory etc, so that is platform specific.

Comment: @pscs Linux sorry, I forgot to mention.